# loop in associative array in json ung jquery and get array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have json file that has surname has 1 value, first_name has 2 valuse in an array, and other object only has 1 value in array.
How will I be able to get the Jhon and Jason?

Here is my json file

```
[{
    "surname": "Vlad", 
    "first_name": [
        "Jhon", 
        "Jason"
    ], 
    "age": 25,

},
{
    "surname": "Vlad", 
    "first_name": [
        "Jhon", 
    ], 
    "age": 25,

},
 {
    "surname": "Vlad", 
    "first_name": [
        "Jhon", 
         "Jason"
    ], 
    "age": 25,

}
]
```

Here is my jquery/javascript code

```
    $.each(data, function (key, val){
        var getNameValue = val.first_name;
        if(getNameValue == getFirstName){
            alert(getNameValue);
        }

    });
```

The value

```
getFirstName
```

is came from an search textbox to enter the surname or first_names.

When I search the word "Jhon" I only get the Array[1] which doesn't have any array inside the first_name.

I want to get all of them Indexes (0 1 2) when I search the word "Jhon".

Answer (score 0):

Array[1] does have an array inside, it is only loose comparison that makes it evaluate in the way you are expecting. Also, you don't need the comma after the element if there are no other elements in that array. You can use `Array.indexOf("nameYouAreLookingFor")`, where `Array` is the variable holding your array. This will return -1 if it is not in the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var firstNames = item.first_name;
    if ($.inArray(getFirstName, firstNames) != -1) {
        alert(getFirstName);
    };
});
```

Comment: not working, it displays all of the object in my array, and only the same value